# Sending emails to addresses with non-ASCII characters

Tags: .net, email, smtp, .net-4.5

We have a small mailing web service, cause not every app can access the SMTP server. Now This evening, the web service couldn't send a mail because the receiving mail address contained some more complex characters, resulting in a `The client or server is only configured for E-mail addresses with ASCII local-parts` error.

After googling for a solution, I found out that you should set the `DeliveryFormat` to `International`.

I've implemented this, but I still keep getting the same error. Adding a watch also tells me that `smtp.IsUnicodeSupported` is still `false`

This is the code at the moment:

```
System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mail = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();   
mail.Subject = mailSubject;
mail.Body = mailBody;
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
mail.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;
mail.HeadersEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient smtp  = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("smtp.mydomain.net");
smtp.DeliveryFormat = SmtpDeliveryFormat.International;
smtp.Send(mail);
```

The property `smtp.transport.ServerSupportsEai` is also still false, but it doesn't seem that contact with the SMTP server has been established at that point.

What else can I do to force the SMTP client to send the mail?
Is it even solvable at the application-end?

Answer (score 1):

Non-ASCII characters in email addresses are only partially supported.

If the domain part contains international characters it can be transformed into the proper [punycode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode) representation, but if there are non-ascii character to the left of the @-sign there does not seem to be an established standard of coding (except for the experimental RFC 5355 which is not compatible with existing SMTP standards).

Comment: So what you're basically saying, the standard has been defined, but it has not yet been implemented in to SMTP standards.

Comment: Yep, or as Andrew Tanenbaum expressed already in the 80s: "The nice thing about standards is that you have so many to choose from". There are lots of experimental RFCs that fix some shortcoming or another, but absolutely no way to convince any software vendor to actually implement changes. Especially in a case where the new feature cannot be used until there is enough widespread adoptation or things will seriously break..

Comment: All right, for now I just have to block those addresses then.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but I solved this by specifying the encoding, like this:

```
var mailMessage = new MailMessage
{
    From = new MailAddress("test@domain.co.zw", "Test User", Encoding.UTF8)
};
```

Comment: this method will set displayEncoding in UTF-8, not the email address:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.mailaddress.-ctor?view=net-7.0#system-net-mail-mailaddress-ctor(system-string-system-string-system-text-encoding)